# "which ruby" different from rvm default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundler

I recently installed Ruby 2.1.1 with RVM, and I set that to the default. In my root directory it correctly sets current to ruby-2.1.1:

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p545 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

$ which ruby
$ /Users/mynamehere/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby
```

But when I move into my rails project, current is set back to 1.9.3, even though default is 2.1.1:

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-1.9.3-p545 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

$ which ruby
$ /Users/mynamehere/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin/ruby
```

Can someone tell me why the current ruby version changes depending on my directory, and how I can set 2.1.1 to be the default? I've tried doing "$ rvm --default use 2.1.1" in my project directory, but that doesn't fix the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Go to your Rails project folder, do `ls -a` and do you see a file called, `.ruby-version`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a `.ruby-version` file in your Rails project folder which establishes the default for that project. Check for that and, if you have it, you can remove it or change it's contents to the version you want to use for that particular Rails project.

It's discussed (rather tersely) in the `rvm` website under [Typical RVM Project Workflow](https://rvm.io/workflow/projects).

You can also define your gemset specific to the project as well. It's a cool feature if you have multiple projects that require different versions.